# MD5 Checksum of certain files changes with FTP Up-/Download

Tags: java, php, ftp, md5, apache-commons-net

I'm using the [Apache Commons NET](http://commons.apache.org/net/) and their [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

Now my case: I've got a file on the server and the same file in the same hierarchy locally. On the server, I generate the MD5-Checksum of the file using PHP's [md5_file()](http://php.net/md5_file). On my machine, I am generating the MD5-Checksum using Apache Commons Digest Utils [md5hex()](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#md5Hex%28java.io.InputStream%29).

Those MD5-Hashes actually quite always matches - except for certain files.

One of the file is the current jQuery-Library. Another of these files is a .ttf Font-File and another one is a regular PHP file (system/libraries/Migration.php from [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)).

Now the amazing part: If I see that those MD5 Checksums are not the same, I upload the local file to the server (or I download the FTP-File to my computer, depends on which one is newer (timestamp)). But no matter what, after the Up- or Download, the MD5 Checksums are still not the same - from exactly the same files. Why?

As I thought, the timestamp could be part of the md5-data, but this is actually impossible because then all the other files would fail too.

I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you sure you're using binary mode when uploading/downloading?

Comment: how do you check the files are exactly the same? maybe there are differences between two text files because the codification.

Comment: @JonSkeet is this an option to use with the FTPClient? Because I looked for that but couldn't find anything...

Comment: @logoff I check it by testing them in the application (the code works the same way as expected). But I did not check about formats and encoding ... would that have an impact on the md5 checksum?

Comment: @FlorianMüller: I don't know, not having used FTPClient. Have you tried using standalone MD5 tools to validate whether the problem is with the file contents or your MD5 checking?

Comment: @JonSkeet nope did only try the DigestUtils. But I've tried those every time so far and I'm quite pleased about the good work Apache had done on this library, so I don't think there's a fault in it.

Comment: @FlorianMüller: Well that's definitely the next thing I'd try. You've got to isolate whether the problem is in the file transfer or the MD5 part, and if it's in the MD5 part, whether it's the Java or PHP side that's broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jon Skeet already mentioned, the usual reason why this happens is that the files are not transferred in binary, but in ASCII mode.

This is supported by the FTPClient documentation for [FTPClient.setFileType()](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setFileType%28int%29), which states:

> The default file type is FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE if this method is never called.

To transfer your file in binary mode using FTPClient, call the `setFileType` before uploading:

```
FTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

The session will stay in binary mode until you change it again.

By the way, timestamps are not an issue, they do not affect the MD5 hash.

Comment: Well, could I actually transfer all of the files in binary mode? What would be the problem (performance?)

Comment: No performance problem. The only one I can think of is that line endings on different systems are different, i.e. `CRLF` on Windows vs. `LF` on Linux. But unless you're on Windows and using Notepad to view text files having Unix-style line endings, you should be fine.

Comment: I've just tested it - that was the problem! Thank you vry much!

Comment: Note that as of 3.6 you have to set the file type **AFTER** the login (if any) otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have comment previlleages so that i am posting as an answer.
I have faced this earlier in one of my projec, FTP clients used to add newline characters in ASCII mode.

Refer the below link for more info
https://superuser.com/questions/39520/downloading-files-with-filezilla-result-in-newline-r-n-n